# Sqlserver PIVOT to turn a "reconstruct" a flat table into columns - why does this not work?

Tags: sql-server, pivot

The system we are using allows a data entry form to be created from multiple user defined fields to satisfy information required on a particular group of different "ORDES". The fields are then stored in a database as such from what is entered:

```
GUID OrderGUID UserDataCode  Value
1    100       OrderName     Breakfast
2    100       OrderDesc     Food you eat before Lunch
3    100       CerealYN      Y
4    100       ToastYN       Y
5    100       ToastDesc     White Bread
6    100       PaperYN       Y
7    100       PaperDesc     The Newsroom
8    101       OrderName     Lunch
9    101       OrderDesc     Food you eat before Dinner
10   101       CerealYN      N
11   101       ToastYN       Y
12   101       ToastDesc     Brown Bread
13   101       PaperYN       Y
14   101       PaperDesc     The MiddayNews
(etc)
```

(in fact this is an Enterprise Hospital software but I have used simpler examples here)

I would like using SQL to return this table PIVOTed like below

```
OrderGUID   OrderName   OrderDESC   CerealYN   ToastYN   ToastDesc    ....
101         Breakfast   Food you..  Y          Y         White Bread  ....
102         Lunch       Food you..  N          Y         Brown Bread  ....
```

I wrote the following SQL based on examples found on the net:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 

SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME([UserDataCode])
FROM (
    SELECT  
        [UserDataCode]
    FROM 
        [XXX].[dbo].[CV3OrderUserData]
    WHERE OrderGUID = 3000680
    ) AS Codes;

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = N'SELECT OrderGUID, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM
        [XXX].[dbo].[CV3OrderUserData]
    PIVOT(Max(Value) 
          FOR UserDataCode IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query

--SELECT @DynamicPivotQuery

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

However while it does the pivot as requested.. and puts the values in the correct new "dynamic" columns, if returns a row for each OrderGUID + Value,
ie:

```
OrderGUID   OrderName    OrderDesc   CerealYN   ToastYN
100         Breakfast    null        null       null  ...
100         null         Food you..  null       null  ...
101         null         null        Y          null  ...
```

etc.etc

What am i doing wrong :( ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your query is the pivot source query has `GUID` column which makes the pivot operator to consider `GUID` column.

To get the expected output you need to remove `GUID` column from the pivot source query.

Here is a `static version` you can convert it to dynamic version as you already did.

```
select * from
(
SELECT OrderGUID,UserDataCode,Value
    FROM
        tst) A
    PIVOT(Max(Value) 
          FOR UserDataCode IN ([OrderName],[OrderDesc],
                               [CerealYN],[ToastYN],
                              [ToastDesc],[PaperYN],
                              [PaperDesc])) AS PVTTable
```

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/01bb3/12)

Comment: Thanks Fireblade - just found it as your notification came up. Went back to basic's tutorial and picked up the error - https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/questions-about-pivoting-data-in-sql-server-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/